# Is it true that carbonic acid should be avoided when one is histamin intolerant?

Tags: diet, allergy

I've read a few contradictionos things about carbonic acid. Some statements say its a histamin liberator (thus produces histamin), while others say the exact opposite.

Now I would like to know if carbonic acid should be avoided when one is histamin intolerant or not (thus if its a histamin liberator,... or not)?

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. It would be helpful if you linked to some of the contradictory sources you've read about carbonic acid. Thanks :)